# Bash: parse shell command string

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, readline

Given a shell command string (`ls a\ b "c d" $f`), can bash parse it into an array, preferrably as `bash` itself would see it after all expansions, right before execution (`([0]=ls [1]='a b' [2]='c d' [3]=<value of $f>)`)? I.e. the read() part of a REPL.

I'd like to write a custom `bind -x` function, and I need to parse the current `READLINE_LINE`. I've tried `read -a`, but that only takes care of backslashes (e.g. `"a b"` gets split into `<"a>` and `<b">`)

Comment: What about nested commands, i.e. `c1 $(c2)`?

Comment: If you **must** use bash, how about [precmd/preexec](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec)?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Nested command should parse as a token list, ( 'c1' '$(' 'c2' ')'  ). Hm, I should revise the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you can make use of the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
parse(){
    declare -g cmd
    local i
    for i in $(seq 1 $#); do
        cmd[$((i-1))]="${!i}"
    done
    declare -p cmd
}
touch "a b" "c d" "e"
f="e"
trap 'eval "parse $BASH_COMMAND"; trap -- DEBUG' DEBUG
ls a\ b "c d" $f
declare -p cmd
```

Comment: This works. You could also `for i; do cmd+=( "$i" ); done` BTW. But, of course, `eval` will run any commands embedded in a $( ) on the command line, so I'm having second thoughts -- maybe I just need a parser that splits correctly on non-escaped whitespace